# Proving a function is odd

Tags: functions

Here is the given question

> Show that 
>   $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^x+1}$$
>   is an odd function

I do know that

> $ f(x) = f(-x)$ is a even function
>   $ f(x) = -f(-x)$ is a odd function

But i cannot seem to simplify f(x) into -f(x) to prove that it is a odd function 
-f(x) is $ -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^x+1}$

So far i have been able to get

> $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}+2^x-2^{x+1}}{2+2^{x+1}}$$

and cannot find a way further to simplify

Comment: $f(x)=-f(-x)$ !

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{2^x+1}+\frac{2^x}{1+2^x}=1$$
Therefore
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^x+1}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^x}{2^x+1}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{-x}+1}=-f(-x)$$
hence $f(x)$ is odd.

Comment: A minus sign missing at the end.

Comment: Of course, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2^{x/2}-2^{-x/2}}{2(2^{x/2}+2^{-x/2})}$ is odd.